# Plastic Command Line: How do I "Undelete" all files?

Tags: plasticscm, undelete

I'm trying to undelete all .wav files in a work space. I've got code to filter all the wave files that were deleted by using:

```
cm hist <sound folders> --format={1}
```

to get all the changesets affecting my sound folders and then filtering through log outputs

```
cm log cs:<changeset>
```

for the `D` deleted file names. Now that I have the names, I intended to use

```
cm undelete
```

but it's asking for `revid` or `itemid` and `cs` information I don't have and can't seem to query since the item is deleted.

I'm hoping there is an awesome command line that might allow me to undelete all files of a certain type. If this is possible from plastic PCM or Plastic Gluon, that is an option also.

Thanks!

Comment: I would use the undelete feature in plastic gluon but the because of the sheer number of files to undelete (thousands) it just is not feasible on a single case by case basis.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

When running the "cm log" command, you can get the revision ids of the items to undelete. This revid is necessry to undelete the items with the "cm undelete" command.

```
cm log cs:1 --itemformat="{newline} {revid} {shortstatus} {path}"
```